# Example Needed: Using arrow() with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to create a geom_path() that has arrows pointing towards the next location in the path.

I can get the path to plot, without issue, for example:

```
df <- (x=1:12, y=20:31, z=1:12)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))
p + geom_point() + geom_path()
```

Now what I'd like to be able to do is plot that point arrows from one element in the path to the next.

Extra marks if you could tell me how to smooth the lines from one element in the path to the next.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`geom_segment` has an `arrow` argument. Here's a short example:

```
library(grid) # needed for arrow function

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
     geom_point() +
     geom_segment(aes(xend=c(tail(x, n=-1), NA), yend=c(tail(y, n=-1), NA)),
                  arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.3,"cm")))
```

[image]

`library(grid)` is needed for `arrow()` function, see [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_segment.html).

Comment: geom_segment worked like a charm, but I'm wondering why you chose to go with geom_segment over what seems to be geom_path's primary function?

Comment: `geom_path` (or `geom_line`) doesn't plot the arrow in each segment, there is only one arrow at the position of the last point.

Comment: @rcs added library(grid), also link to the image is broken.